# Update list of divs after ajax post

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this code that loads some `div`

```
<input class="input-large" placeholder="Notat" id="txtNewNote" type="text">
        <button class="btn" id="btnAddNote" type="button">Lagre</button>

@foreach (var item in Model.UserNotes)
    {
        <div class="alert" id="divNote-@item.UserNoteID">
        <button type="button" class="close" onclick="NoteDeleteClicked(@item.UserNoteID)" id="btnCloseNote">&times;</button>
        <strong>@item.User.Name - @item.Added</strong><br />
            @item.Text
        </div>
    }
```

Then I run this javascript when the user enter more text:

```
  var Text = $("#txtNewNote").val();
  var Added = Date.now();
  vvar UserID = $("#hiddenUserID").text();
  $.post("/api/apiUserNotes",{ Text : Text, Added: Added, UserID: UserID }, function()        { //need functianality for updating the list of divs above });
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction here. I cannot just create the div after the post are done because I need to fetch data from the database so that the information in the `div` are correct.

Comment: what you want to add to those Divs?

Comment: can your api return a list of UserNotes? or you return html?

Comment: My api can Return whatever. Right now its json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mainly two approaches:

1. **`apiUserNotes` returns HTML** - This approach is a bit easier to maintain since you have only one template. But it is also more restricting in the sense that HTML is good for showing, but not so much for manipulating it.
2. **`apiUserNotes` returns JSON** - This is more flexible since a JSON API can be consumed by pretty much anything, from HTML to native iOS or Android apps, as it's much easier to manipulate. It's also more work though, as you then have templates both on the server-side (your Razor view) as well as on the client-side (your HTML/JavaScript).

This is more or less what #1 would look like:

You first make a partial view to display user notes:

_UserNotes.cshtml:

```
<div id="user-notes">
    @foreach (var item in Model.UserNotes)
    {
        <div class="alert" id="divNote-@item.UserNoteID">
            <button type="button" class="close" onclick="NoteDeleteClicked(@item.UserNoteID)" id="btnCloseNote">&times;</button>
            <strong>@item.User.Name - @item.Added</strong><br />
                @item.Text
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Once you have this partial view, you can consume it from your view:

```
<input class="input-large" placeholder="Notat" id="txtNewNote" type="text">
<button class="btn" id="btnAddNote" type="button">Lagre</button>
@Html.Partial("_UserNotes")
```

And from your `apiUserNotes` action:

```
public PartialViewResult apiUserNotes(string text, DateTime added, int userID)
{
    // TODO: save new note
    var notes = yourRepo.GetUserNotes(userID);
    return PartialView("_UserNotes", notes);
}
```

Finally, your client-side scripts simply overrites the div containing all user notes:

```
var data = {
    text = $("#txtNewNote").val(),
    added = Date.now(),
    userID = $("#hiddenUserID").text()
};

$.post("/apiUserNotes", data, function (result) {
    $('#user-notes').html(result);
});
```

There are of course much more efficient ways of doing this. For example, you don't need to reload *all* user notes; only the one your just added. But hopefully this gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can access above Divs in following way, and update as per your requirement.

```
 $.post("/api/apiUserNotes",{ Text : Text, Added: Added, UserID: UserID },
 function()
  { 
   //need functianality for updating the list of divs above 
   $("div.alert").each(....)
});
```